# Using cURL to read JSON data

Tags: php, json, curl

Using Chrome to inspect the url: http://www.wizards.com/Magic/PlaneswalkerPoints/76954206# I am able to see the url where the JSON data is grabbed from:

Request URL:http://www.wizards.com/Magic/PlaneswalkerPoints/JavaScript/GetPointsSummary/76954206

Running my code:

```
$user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.72 Safari/537.36'; 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1); // Fail on errors
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); // allow redirects
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5); // times out after 5s
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json','Content-Length: ' . strlen($json)));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

// receive server response ...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

// further processing ....
if ($server_output == "OK") { 
  print_r($ch);
} else {
  echo "Boo";
}
```

Leaves me with a blank page. It's not returning JSON, only the redirect error page.

Is there a certain call I am missing to grab the JSON data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php

$url = 'http://www.wizards.com/Magic/PlaneswalkerPoints/JavaScript/GetPointsSummary/76954206';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '');
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
```

Output:

> {"Result":true,"SessionExpired":false,"Data":[{"Key":"LifetimePoints","Value":6016,"ReplaceElement...

Comment: Thank you. Idk why I was trying to over complicate the whole thing.